# Trying to get \n to work in django/html after using python for script

Tags: python, html, django

I created a Python script that retrieves a list of payments that go to my companies email. I thought it would be interesting to do for Cashapp/Venmo payments to compile them. However I really want the site to format the payments/details so that each payment is on a new line. In the python I put final = final + ..... + \n for the string that is to be used in the html. Yet `\n` will not work in HTML no matter what I try to do.

In my views.py I set data=final, then call it here in the HTML.

```
<body>
    <button onclick="location.href='{% url 'script' %}'" >
        Check new payments
    </button> <hr>
    {% if data %}
    {{data}}
    {% endif %}
</body>
```

This prints out all the necessary data yet it is in one continuous string and does not include the \n. If I print it in the terminal it includes these. It is likely because html does not recognize \n I assume, I just don't know an alternative for this.

Comment: The trivial case is to wrap the verbatim text in `<pre>`...`</pre>` tags. There are options like `<code>` etc depending on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Not a stellar duplicate but hopefully enough to get you started.

Comment: Often `<br>` in formatted HTML. Note, the Django template engine will escape `<>` unless it's safe'd `{{data|safe}` or is substituting a safe string ( generated with `format_html`, `mark_safe`, etc.)

Comment: @tripleee thank you that worked!

Comment: @nigel222 thank you I figured it out